# Add at once all the new files to VCS in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.0

In one of my projects on Android Studio 2.0, I have several files across the whole app that are not added yet to my VCS. Is there a way to quickly find all those files in order to add them all at once to VCS?

Worse case I will just add them one by one but it is a bit tedious.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you can! Just open the "Version control" panel, you will see an "Unversioned files" change list. Right click on it > Add to VCS.

[image]

Comment: It was well hidden! To give more details, it is indeed in the "Version Control" panel, inside the "Local Changes" tab, below the "Default" list.